# Como ver memoria consumida pela aplicação web?

Tags: java, jvm

Estou com uma aplicação web com Spring rodando, gostaria de saber como faço pra ver a memoria consumida pela mesma.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `Java Mission Control`. Uma aplicação da Oracle que Server para monitorar o desempenho das aplicações aplicação que rodam na JVM.

http://oracle.com/missioncontrol

https://www.prosysopc.com/blog/using-java-mission-control-for-performance-monitoring